# pywin32/win32com unable to pull more than 1537 emails at a time

Tags: email, outlook, count, pywin32, win32com

I am working with pywin32/win32com to try and pull the sender information of ALL emails in my inbox. My code works, but only ever shows 1537 emails no matter who runs it. I have 2-3k emails in my default folder in my inbox, and a coworker has closer to 20k emails in his default inbox folder, but both of us run this script and only see the same number, 1537. Can someone please fill me in as to what could be causing this limitation?

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
rootlist = {}
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) #6 = Inbox (without mails from the subfolder)
messages = inbox.Items
PidTagSenderSmtpAddress = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5D01001F"

for i in range(0, messages.Count):
    messaging = inbox.Items[i]
    if messaging.Class == 43 or messaging.Class == 69: #detect if mailitem
        sender = messaging.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PidTagSenderSmtpAddress)
        #print(sender)
        if sender in rootlist:
            rootlist[str(sender)][0] = rootlist[str(sender)][0] + 1
        else:
            rootlist[str(sender)] = [1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never loop through all items in a folder, use `Items.Find`/`FindNext` or `Items.Restrict` with a query like

```
@SQL="http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5D01001F" = 'user@domain.demo'
```

Comment: I am trying to intentionally go through all items and all folders, and only exclude calendar invites. I am trying to count the number of times each email shows up and examine the entire box. Is there a better way to do this? Or do I just not understand the mechanism for using the find function?

I am reading through the method reference for the Item class via 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.find
and i see in here there is a way to search through the objects by sent email, but nothing that just dumps the list. Is it better to do this via an offline dump?

Comment: If you still want to iterate through all items in a folder, use `MAPIFolder.GetTable` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folder.gettable

Comment: That's it! That's what I was looking for! Thank you!!! :)